# Unable to show 4 products in row in subcategory/shop page woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I'm unable to show 4 products in a row, I just put the filter in my `themes/functions.php`.

Code is below:

```
function loop_columns(){
 return 4;
}
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns',999);
```

When I return 3, all working is fine, but when I put 4 here, it shows the grid like this:

---

```
Product |
______________________________________
Product | Product | Product | Product
______________________________________
Product | Product | Product | Product
______________________________________
Product | Product | Product | Product
```

---

**Note: Why does `product` display on top?** Please help me. Live link of this issue is
**http://csjs.com/product-category/bhai-guriqbal-singh-ji-books/**

More detail : 4 products in a row, But after adding filter for 4 columns in functions.php, This problem occur. If somebody go to direct my shop page everything is fine, but if somebody open a category wise products its not showing well, because i also show sub-categories of the parent on shop page.

Note: If i reduce the width upper 3 columns, This single product in a row shift on above row. But My requirement is, One row show only sub categories and grid show the products.

All the grid items are a part of same ul element, its class is products.

Comment: Almost assuredly this is the CSS of your theme. Please use Firebug or other element inspectors to investigate further.

Comment: Please include your CSS. A demo of the page would help us.

Comment: See the latest edit, Live link is added with more details